# is it possible to use alternative dns manager

Tags: domain-name-system, domain

long time ago I bought a cheap hosting and it came with a domain name. but now I want more control over my domain name, and their cheap panel just don't have access to edit the entries. the only thing I can edit is the <strike>dns server address</strike> nameserver address.

are there some free/pay dns server which I can change to, and will allow me to have full control over the dns table of my domain? or the only way is to do a transfer

Comment: ["Shopping questions"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) are a bad fit for Stack Exchange sites. These services do exist, but you need to do your own research to find one that meets your needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can edit the nameserver address(es) for the domain, which I assume is what you meant by "the dns server address", then you can sign up for external DNS services like [ZoneEdit](http://zoneedit.com). The DNS provider you select should tell you what values to set your domain nameservers to.

Answer (score 0):

I've used powerdns.net and can attest to its usefulness. Its also very cheap.

Lots of people use Amazon's Route 53 for DNS.

If you have your own server (preferably a pair of servers for redundancy) you can setup your own name server on it using something like BIND.